# Bash script - cycle through MySQL records and update record based on user select

Tags: bash

I'm a bit stuck, I need to loop through all of my mysql records and update one of the fields based on user input.

I was going to use the following to do the loop:

```
mysql -uuser -ppassword -s -e "SELECT company,product,category FROM MyTable"|while read varcomp varprod varcat;do
```

..and then use a PS3 select to provide the option:

```
PS3 "Please select new category: "
select opt1 in "Blocks" "Dolls" "Puzzles"
```

...before using, the following to update:

```
mysql -uuser -ppassword -s -e "UPDATE MyTable SET Category='$opt1' WHERE company='$varcomp' AND product='$varprod'"
```

...and then closing the loop.

I just can't seem to get all of the components to work together. I think it's because I'm using a while loop? Any advice on the best way to do this would be appreciated...

Comment: Should all rows be updated with the new category at once, or should the user be prompted for each row?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
while read -u 4 varcomp varprod varcat; do 
    echo "Company: $varcomp - Product: $varprod - Category: $varcat"
    PS3="Please select new category: "
    select opt in "Blocks" "Dolls" "Puzzles"; do
        mysql -uuser -ppassword -s -e "UPDATE MyTable SET Category='$opt' WHERE company='$varcomp' AND product='$varprod';"
        break
    done
done 4< <(mysql -uuser -ppassword -s --skip-column-names -e "SELECT company,product,category FROM MyTable;")
```

You had the right idea, but the issue with using `select` inside a `while read` loop is that `select` and `read` both read input from stdin, so `select` would read all the SQL lines instead of prompting for user input. Instead, we redirect the `mysql` results to file descriptor `4`, then tell `read` to use that instead of stdin, while `select` still reads from stdin as usual.

Note that if a user puts in a different value for `select` (eg 8 instead of 1, 2 or 3) then `$opt` will be null. You could replace the lines inside the `select` with:

```
[[ -n "$opt" ]] && mysql -uuser -ppassword -s -e "UPDATE MyTable SET Category='$opt' WHERE company='$varcomp' AND product='$varprod';" && break
```

This will keep prompting the user for input until they give a valid response.